# Recompile assemblies to separate appdomains in NET 5

Tags: .net-5, appdomain

I have a NET 5.0 console application, from which I am trying to compile and execute external code BUT also be able to update the code, unload the previously created appdomain and re-compile everything.

This is my entire static class that handles code compilation and assembly loading

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

namespace Scripting
{
    public static class ScriptCompiler
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, AppDomain> _appDomainDict = new();
        
        public static object CompileScript(string scriptpath)
        {
            var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(File.ReadAllText(scriptpath));
            
            //Adding basic references
            List<PortableExecutableReference> refs = new List<PortableExecutableReference>();
            var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.dll")));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Private.CoreLib.dll")));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Core.dll")));
            refs.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")));


            // A single, immutable invocation to the compiler
            // to produce a library
            string hash_name = scriptpath.GetHashCode();

            if (_appDomainDict.ContainsKey(hash_name))
            {
                AppDomain.Unload(_appDomainDict[hash_name]);
                _appDomainDict.Remove(hash_name);
            }
            
            AppDomain new_domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(hash_name);
            _appDomainDict[hash_name] = new_domain;

            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(hash_name)
              .WithOptions(
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                                             optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release,
                                             allowUnsafe:true))
              .AddReferences(refs.ToArray())
              .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            EmitResult compilationResult = compilation.Emit(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (compilationResult.Success)
            {
                // Load the assembly
                Assembly asm = new_domain.Load(ms.ToArray());
                
                object main_ob = asm.CreateInstance("SomeClass");
                ms.Close();
                return main_ob;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Diagnostic codeIssue in compilationResult.Diagnostics)
                {
                    string issue = $"ID: {codeIssue.Id}, Message: {codeIssue.GetMessage()}," +
                        $" Location: { codeIssue.Location.GetLineSpan()}," +
                        $" Severity: { codeIssue.Severity}";
                    Callbacks.Logger.Log(typeof(NbScriptCompiler), issue, LogVerbosityLevel.WARNING);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Its all good when I am trying load the assembly in the current domain and execute from the instantiated object. The problem with this case is that since I wanna do frequent updates to the code, even if I make sure that the assembly names are different. I'll end up loading a ton of unused assemblies to the current domain.

This is why I've been trying to create a new domain and load the assembly there. But for some reason I get a platform not supported exception. Is this not possible to do in NET 5? Are there any workarounds or am I doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that AppDomain support for NET Core + is very limited and in particular there seems to be only one appdomain

> On .NET Core, the AppDomain implementation is limited by design and
> does not provide isolation, unloading, or security boundaries. For
> .NET Core, there is exactly one AppDomain. Isolation and unloading are
> provided through AssemblyLoadContext. Security boundaries should be
> provided by process boundaries and appropriate remoting techniques.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=net-6.0

And indeed, when trying to use `AssemblyLoadContext` and create object instances through these contexts everything worked like a charm!

One last note is that if the created context is not marked as collectible, its not possible to unload it. But this can be very easily set during `AssemblyLoadContext` construction.